# How To Rewriterules PHP with Htaccess LIKE Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I will make site like wordpress, multiple rewrite rule but on htaccess file is very simple. ex:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If i see this rule is simple, but how logic on PHP file? I mean, if i use this php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page'] AND $_GET['page']=="profil")
{
    echo "example";
}
elseif(isset($_GET['page']) AND $_GET['page']=="news" AND isset($_GET['p']))
{
    echo "This is $_GET[p]";
}
?>
```

And with htaccesslike here

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /MyTest/
RewriteRule ^profil\.html$ index.php?page=profil [L]
RewriteRule ^site-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=news&p=$1 [L]
</Ifmodule>
```

But this is not mass rewrite like wordpress, please help me to rewrite rule like WORDPRESS logic.

Comment: The wordpress index file routes based on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. This variable contains the url that was in the url bar of the browser, not the url it was rewritten to.

Comment: and then how the url from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] read from php script, sir?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress rewrites everything to one page, the router, which loads the correct pages to display the content. Simply use the same rules as for wordpress. In the index file you use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the originating url, process it to get the information you want out of it, then load the right page. You probably want to use this with actual seo-urls.

```
<?php
$urlparts = explode( "/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

$page = end( $urlparts );
$matches = Array();

if( $page == "profil.html" ) {
  include( "profil.php" );
} else if( preg_match( "/site-([0-9]+)\.html/", $page, $matches ) ) {
  $num = $matches[1];
  include( "news.php" );
} else {
  include( "404.php" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks sumurai8.
But, how if will create permalink like
http://domain/game/this-is-my-article (For read article, and game is category)
http://domain/cat/game (for desc category list)

Comment: You add to the if-else statement. The first urls you should handle are the most specific ones, then the most specific regex urls, then the less specific regex urls. Finally you have the 404 page.